# How can I get the latest version of Assault Cube?

Tags: packaging, development, motu, updates

The one that is currently up is pretty outdated; I was just curious if one such as myself could update, package then upload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assaultcube is currently synced directly from Debian. You might consider [reporting a wishlist bug](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting) against the package in Debian.

If you are interested in trying to do it yourself, this might be a good place to start:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/HandsOn#Tutorial%202:%20Updating%20a%20Package

You would also need to update the associated “assaultcube-data” package. Then you would need to follow the [sponsorship process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SponsorshipProcess) to get the package uploaded.

There is already an [open bug](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/assaultcube/+bug/621704) about this in Ubuntu.